# redirect CNN to different website on my own mac

Tags: networking, redirection, osx-mavericks

Not sure if this is the right site.  Compulsively alt-tab and type CNN.com for some reason.  Is there a way to redirect that to a different site, e.g. nytimes, to break the habit or at least get better news?   (Mac OS X)

The file `/private/etc/hosts` seems to want only IP addresses on the left side, and the IP address changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have firefox installed, then install the greasemonkey plugin. Then add the following script and the CNN home screen will automatically redirect you to nytimes:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        CNN Redirect
// @namespace   null
// @description Redirects CNN to NY Times
// @include     http://cnn.com/
// @include     http://www.cnn.com/
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==


window.location.replace( "http://www.nytimes.com" );
```

If you want to redirect to another site, it is pretty easy to edit.